# How to print a Bitmap Image?

Tags: image, printing, bitmap, c++-cli

I have a Bitmap Image that I would like to print (on paper). I have searched google and none of the examples there worked for me. I would not like to use any external libraries. 
Help?

Comment: What does 'print' mean, like ink and paper on a printer? Or just display on a screen?

Comment: I meant as with ink and paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on a Linux platform, the *NetPBM* software can help.  So can *ImageMagick.*  However, do you not wish to use any external libraries?  That's quite a restriction!

Good luck.